# Can't ping domain controller from PC on a remote subnet

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory

In trying to connect a PC from a remote subnet to our domain controller.

Initally the domain controller couldn't contact the pc, but resetting the vpn connection resolved that. 
Currently the PC from the remote subnet can resolve the domain name and a tracert, results in the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 192.168.0.26

Tracing route to ad.domain.com [192.168.0.26] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.202.1
  2    21 ms    38 ms    20 ms  172.X.X.X
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

It successfully is able to route to other pcs on the network

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 192.168.0.8

Tracing route to 192.168.0.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.202.1
  2    58 ms    20 ms    23 ms  172.X.X.X
  3    40 ms    40 ms    44 ms  192.168.0.8

 Trace complete.
```

I can't see anything on my firewall that would be blocking or dropping the connection,

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

EDIT: IPCONFIG RESULTS

```
C:\Users\Administrator.HQDC>ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ad
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : domain.com
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.com
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3F-20-F4
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b916:e720:ea8b:a326%14(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.26(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352324649
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-C4-A2-0C-00-0C-29-A9-80-01
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.26
                                   127.0.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{715545D0-9D5A-4707-91A2-876364FA3227}:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Remote PC results

```
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WHWAREHOSUE3
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F8-BC-12-96-5C-1A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3545:b1d:1bf0:75c8%11(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.202.233(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.202.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 247996262
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C8-49-EE-F8-BC-12-96-5C-1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                    8.8.4.4
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{EA82B91F-FB1E-45EC-B7EF-5B32A6C0585E}:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A PC on the remote network, or all PCs on the remote network?

Comment: I can't ping from all pcs on the remote network currently to the domain controller.

Comment: Can you ping the DC from computers on the **SAME** network?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the local firewall on the pc/dc?

Comment: Can you post "IPconfig /all" results for both workstation and DC?

Comment: Still working on this, have added the subnet in the AD sites and services, but haven't had any luck. Much appreciate all the help so far.